# How to load image in image control of ASP.NET from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have created a new folder in my project and save images in that folder. I also store the path in a Database.

Now I want to load the image in ASP.NET image control but I am unable to do so.

Here is code for storing path.

```
if (ImgUpload.HasFile)
{
    string fileName = ImgUpload.FileName;
    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/FacultyPics/");
    int fileLength = ImgUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    string fileextention = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    fileextention = fileextention.ToLower();
    string link = "~/Images/FacultyPics/" + fileName;   //this link will be stored in database
    if (fileLength < 1048576)
    {
        if (fileextention == ".jpg" || fileextention == ".png" || fileextention == ".gif" || fileextention == ".bmp")
        {
            ImgUpload.SaveAs(filePath + fileName);
            BAL.Pic = link;
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Only Image files are allowed";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Max file size allowed is 1 MB";
    }
}
```

Img is an ASP.NET image control but it is not showing image.

```
Img.ImageUrl = Page.ResolveUrl(dt.Rows[0][7].ToString());
```

Comment: I think that you must do it like that Page.ResolveClientURL(dt.Rows[0][7].ToString());

Comment: I'd check what you're getting back from `dt.Rows[0][7]` first... the code you've given us provides absolutely no clue as to how you're getting the url back from the database

Comment: @SherifAhmed... Sorry! I edited the question.

I have also tried with both Page.ResolveUrl() and Page.ResolveClientURL() still no image loaded.

Comment: @freefaller.. It is returning..

../../Images/FacultyPics/11130256_881632985226719_6209

Comment: is this file exits in this path? this is first, second check how the path is resolved by your aspx page based on the application structure (your application folders structure).

Comment: @SherifAhmed... oh thank you.. thank you thank you very much.. kindly post this comment as answer I have found the error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check how the path is resolved by your aspx page based on the application structure (your application folders structure)